# PHP - How to order images without MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, sorting, drag-and-drop

I use to upload images into folders giving them randomic names in order to avoid double names but now I need to **order these images**.
I found a guide (with nice drug and drop method) but it needs to store images on database.
Is there a way to do it without passing for a database? Or better...is there a way to order them by saving only names and/or paths on db, keeping files in directories?
I red that storing images on db is not the better solution so I'm searching for a guide for CRUD and sorting images (with or without a db, it depends on your advices).

How would you do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more about how you need to sort the images? By what criteria?

Comment: One option would be to implement https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette

Comment: *saving only names and/or paths on db, keeping files in directories* ... that's pretty much standard practice for dealing with images in web apps.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
I need to be free to sort images as my choice. A drag and drop method is the top to explain my need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the path in the database and then query and order.

And you can get the files in a folder and then order them.

You can use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the files. It will return an array, and then you can sort the array using [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for your reply.
Ok but what's the better method to change the order? An input text (not very smart), AJAX, a drag and drop method?